# Pandas dataframe to check an empty string

Tags: python, pandas, string

I would like to differentiate an empty string with certain lengths           and a regular string such as `G1234567`. The length of the empty string right now in my dataset is 8 but I would not guarantee all future empty string will still have length of 8.

This is what the column looks like when I print it out:

```
0               
1               
2               
3               
4               
  
9461    G6000000
9462    G6000001
9463    G6000002
9464    G6000003
9465    G6000004
Name: Sub_ID, Length: 9466, dtype: object
```

If I apply `pd.isnull()` on the entire column, I will have a mask populated with all False. I would like to ask if there is anyway for me to differentiate between an empty string with certain lengths and a string that is actually populated with something.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following creates a mask for all the cells in your DataFrame (`df`) that are just empty strings (strings that only contain whitespaces):

```py
df.applymap(lambda column: column.isspace())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out the ```isspace()``` method. I applied the method directly to the column instead of the whole dataframe and it works perfectly. Thanks again!